# Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 3.1 WinForm view timeout (Studio 16.7.3)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I've upgraded Studio 2019 to 16.7.3 and I cannot open a fresh .NET Core Winforms file in the designer.

I've turned on the Winform logging to Verbose
(Tools / Options / Windows Forms Designer / General / Logging Level = Verbose.

I can see in the Output Window / Windows Forms this error:

> Timed out waiting for the design tools server process launch to
> complete.

- No different running as administrator.
- There is just a single project in the solution.
- The default project has this at the top: Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop"

Sadly, most of what I see on the net is related to the old versions is Studio when WinForms support was initially introduced.  i.e.  No 2020 dates in the posts : (

Edit:  I have learned that rebooting Windows will allow the designer to open.  This just works for awhile and then something happens where it stops working.  A reboot will bring it back.

Comment: Try opening a new project and then from menu File : SaveAll to a folder you have read/write permission.

Comment: We had improved startup time of the DesignToolsServer.exe in the recent release, if you can, please try a preview, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview.
One hint - verbose logging slows down designer, you might want to disable it after the problem is identified.